# "Совершить экскурсию" - можно ли так сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Здравствуйте!
Написал как-то в тексте "совершить экскурсию", а потом показалось, что звучит как-то некрасиво. Можно ли экскурсию совершать? А если нет, то как лучше сказать?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Именно так и говорят.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

СОВЕРШИТЬ, 1. Сделать, осуществить (книжн.). С. подвиг. С. преступление.  Самолет совершил посадку. 2. Заключить, оформить (офиц.). С. сделку.

Глагол "совершить" - многозначный, но при этом имеет оттенок книжности, официальности и высокого стиля. Кроме того, область применения для "совершить" настолько разнообразна, что  иногда мы начинаем сомневаться в правильности конкретного словосочетания.

Тем не менее,  выражение "совершить путешествие" занесено в современные словари и активно используется. Этот тот случай, когда в языке есть потребность в слове с нейтральным значением,но слово это пока не найдено.

А пока туристические агентства приглашают нас   совершать экскурсии, путешествия и  увлекательные прогулки. Также мы можем ПРИНЯТЬ УЧАСТИЕ во всех этих мероприятиях.